# Can't run my selenide tests on Docker image without headless mode

Tags: java, docker, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I'm trying to run my Selenide test on the Docker image with maven and Google Chrome browser
If I use this command:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum mvn -Dtest=DebugTestSuite test
```

everything goes perfectly

BUT I don't need headless mode and if I try to run my tests without it with the following command:

```
mvn -Dtest=DebugTestSuite test
```

then it crashes with the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I tried to use the Selenium method to run a WebDriver instead of the Selenide to apply some options to the ChromeDriver so now the code looks like this

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get(WsUrlGenerator.getBaseUrl());
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
```

instead of just

```
        baseUrl = WsUrlGenerator.getBaseUrl();
        open("");
```

And all of this works perfectly when run manually with IDE or with the headless mode, but fails miserably otherwise

Chrome version: `114.0.5735.198-1~deb11u1`
Chromedriver version: `114.0.5735.90`

Is there a versions mismatch or something?

P.S. Also it starts to crash on Docker either way if I update Selenide to any version later then 13.0